# Typescript generic associative array

Tags: typescript, generics, associative-array, typescript-generics

I would like to get deep value from the object, for example result when generic is "books":

```
fieldName: {author: "", langauge: "", translation: ""}
```

```
export const COLLECTIONS_MOCKUP = {
   books: {
      author: "",
      language: "",
      translation: "",
   },
   vehicle: {
      model: "",
      type: "",
      color: "",
   },
}

export interface IOptionalField<T> {
   fieldName: typeof COLLECTIONS_MOCKUP[T]; // how to make it work, it throws an error
   valueType: string | number | boolean | Date;
   isAdded?: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a generic constraint, so that `T` must be a key of `COLLECTIONS_MOCKUP`.

```
export interface IOptionalField<T extends keyof typeof COLLECTIONS_MOCKUP> {
   fieldName: typeof COLLECTIONS_MOCKUP[T];
   valueType: string | number | boolean | Date;
   isAdded?: boolean;
}
```

This works as you expected:

```
const books: IOptionalField<"books"> = {
    fieldName: {
        author: "",
        language: "",
        translation: ""
    },
    valueType: 0
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta&ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=21&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wMIHkAyOCiGAKgJJYByAygPoCyWGA0gKoAKcAvHAN4BQcAgEYQIAa1QAuHvwGyAhgFcYAC2hSAROoA0M2XAA2c5AHMFc48A3bdsmFCOpDMAJYorO2QF8PAgG7BlZwR9S2k9AQBbCAATYH13GwEYAE8wUM0fPSR9NTgM3W9eT15eUEhYOGdkGGAoADM5BGA4MjAXFDl9ADFnOOiAHiI4UBrkaNQ4UWBkiDq4FLTZuGw8QlIKGnomNgA%20MIE63v1o8jkI0IXgJZWCYjIqOgYWVgBtIgBdAG5dX06FYCIqVC6CgVWMcAAPnBkAoIoJapC4MIICEjIiACJyGrfWTOVAAQWisWiAH4pMjUchvsUSkg0PBkeIpK12shOj0%20v11IzUOo9lw%20HpDn1TucpILwgJFCpcvlJQJDCYzBYEvL5vY0E5XMgrDZCnpfvp-oC0lIAAxFIA)